# Specifying multiple rails master keys for the development machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rails 7.0
Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1
```

I am developing a Rails app on my local machine, and have the following in my .zshrc:

```
export RAILS_MASTER_KEY='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
export RAILS_ENV='development'
```

I am starting another project, and will still need to do maintenance work on the old project, and while I have the option to the rails master key in the config folder, that's an issue, because I don't have it in my repo, for obvious reasons, and I occasionally need to remove the local directory and re-clone the repo.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
export RAILS_MASTER_KEY_PROJ1='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
export RAILS_MASTER_KEY_PROJ2='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

and tell each app to look for the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

cant you just have them have their own master.key files and just add them to git-ignore? if you need to re clone the repo you can just generate new ones?